# How can I screen share/VNC to a Linux system (Ubuntu 16.04) from my MAC (10.11)?

Tags: imac, unix, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'd like to use screen sharing/I'd like to VNC to a Linux OS desktop from my Mac. Mac OS version: OS X El Capitan, 10.11.15A2301. Ubuntu version: 16.04.5 LTS. I have my Mac configured to accept VNC connections by enabling file sharing, remote login and remote management and I use it to VNC to other Mac systems but I'd like to VNC to a Linux system this time. I'm assuming I'd have to use some kind of sudo apt install command to install something and enable this functionality?

Please do let me know any methods you may be familiar with, thank you.

Comment: I hear RealVNC works pretty good, but there are a lot of VNC clients for the Mac. No need to use/install a package manager just search for "VNC Mac" there are quite a few out there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to download any VNC client, as a basic one is built-in.

Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server.

Then in the address bar `vnc://<your server ip or hostname>`. Something like:

[image: VNC from Finder]

I hope it will help,
Jarek

Answer (score 1):

I just tried connecting a macOS 10.14.5 to RealVNC 6.4.1 on a Raspbian Buster.

To make it work, I had to disable encryption and configure VNC password instead of (Interactive) UNIX password authentication.

There is no clipboard or observation mode support and I wouldn't use it through a WAN because of the lack of encryption, but it works.